# How to write a function to clean a memory pool in C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct _anyT {
int val;
} anyT;

#define UNITS 10 

typedef union _data_block {
                union _data_block *next;
                anyT the_type;

} data_block;

static data_block *free_list = NULL; 

static void moremem(void) {
  int i;
  data_block *more = calloc(sizeof(data_block),UNITS);
  for(i = 0; i < UNITS; i++) {
        more[i].next = free_list;
        free_list = more + i;
  }
}

anyT *allocanyT(void) {
  data_block *current;
  if(free_list == NULL) {
        moremem();
        return allocanyT();
  }
  current = free_list;
  free_list = free_list->next;
  return &(current->the_type);

}

void freeanyT(anyT *x)
{
  ((data_block *)x)->next = free_list;
  free_list = (data_block *)x;
}

void clearpool() {  
data_block *head;
anyT* cur;
for(head=free_list;head;head=free_list) {
    free_list=free_list->next;
    cur=(anyT*)&head->the_type;
    free(cur);
}
}
```

As code shown above, the function clearpool() in fact does not work !!! I am wondering
if any expert can explain me why and help me solve it. thank you in advance.

Best Regards,

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? What happens?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "does not work"; I see a few things that *could* be problems, but I don't know whether they are.  Please describe what this does and what you expected it to do.

Comment: the clearpool function is supposed to clean up those allocated objects in the pool."does not work" means it in fact does not do 
its job as I expect after I use valgrind to check. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you wanted a struct, not a union for _data_block. The recursive union makes my head turn inside out. You have more problems, but this line:

`cur=(anyT*)&head->the_type;`

suggests that you think `&head->the_type` is different from `&head->next`, which it isn't.